# Third Party Login using Identity in asp.Net core

Tags: asp.net-core

[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

```
        LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
            ExternalLogins = (await signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList()
        };

        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");

            return View("Login", loginViewModel);
        }

        // Get the login information about the user from the external login provider
        var info = await signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error loading external login information.");

            return View("Login", loginViewModel);
        }

        // If the user already has a login (i.e if there is a record in AspNetUserLogins
        // table) then sign-in the user with this external login provider
        var signInResult = await signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider,
            info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

        if (signInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        // If there is no record in AspNetUserLogins table, the user may not have
        // a local account
        else
        {
            // Get the email claim value
            var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

            if (email != null)
            {
                // Create a new user without password if we do not have a user already
                var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = new IdentitiyUser
                    {
                        UserName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
                        Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)
                    };

                    await userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                    // await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                }

                // Add a login (i.e insert a row for the user in AspNetUserLogins table)
                await userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we cannot find the user email we cannot continue
            ViewBag.ErrorTitle = $"Email claim not received from: {info.LoginProvider}";
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Please contact support on abc@xyz.com";

            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

This is the error

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')
System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject, string propertyKey, string propertyValue)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')
System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject, string propertyKey, string propertyValue)
System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(string type, string value)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>.GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.CreateAsync(TUser user)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(TUser user)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, IEnumerable additionalClaims)
EmployeeManagement.Controllers.AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl, string remoteError) in AccountController.cs
+
await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()

Answer (score 1):

The actual exception is complaining that there's an empty claim (that's the "value cannot be null" part), which is trying to be instantiated by some of the ASP.NET Core internals.

The more relevant bit in your case is probably which claim is empty. Looking at that stack trace, there are three claims that might be created as part of the UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.GenerateClaimsAsync() method: user ID, user name, and security stamp ([link](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Core/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs#:%7E:text=cref%3D%22ClaimsIdentity%22/%3E.%3C/returns%3E-,protected%20virtual%20async%20Task%3CClaimsIdentity%3E%20GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser%20user),%7D,-%7D)). I don't think we can tell from the question snippet alone which of the three it is, but ID and name seem like prime suspects.